# Can Chrome print out CSS inches exactly on printer

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

It seems when I set my css print styles and print in chrome, it does not match what I set in my CSS.

Any way to get it working correctly?

Comment: are you using any percentages, or defining only with set values? and are there any margins, padding, or containing element styles that would throw this off? and have you tested using a basic page with the minimum required elements and styling to double check?

Comment: Chrome doesn't print nicely - it's got kerning issues for fonts, cuts pages off etc. I'd say this is a problem with webkit.

Comment: @FabianTamp in my experience, Chrome is far superior at printing compareed with the other browsers

Comment: @Blowsie Good to know; might be due to differences in OS. I primarily use Windows and have found that IE prints most reliably, with Firefox coming in second.

Comment: @BrettWeber I am using inches (css) and tried a simple page with just a rectangle set to inches. Does not print accurately on Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Have you tried setting html, body { zoom : 1.0; } ?

Comment: @BrettWeber Just tried it but no luck.

Comment: @Scott Yu - I'm all out of ideas, but I would [report an issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en) with chrome about it

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the browser will resize the viewport to fit on the page. However, there are some print-specific CSS rules you could experiment along. The main one is the size attribute:

```
    @media print {
        @page {
            size: A4 portrait;
        }
    }
```

A bit more about the page size rule:

**auto** − The page box will be set to the size and orientation of the target sheet.

**landscape** − Overrides the target's orientation. The page box is the same size as the target, and the longer sides are horizontal.

**portrait** − Overrides the target's orientation. The page box is the same size as the target, and the shorter sides are horizontal.

**[length]** − Length values for the 'size' property create an absolute page box. If only one length value is specified, it sets both the width and height of the page box. Percentage values are not allowed for the 'size' property.